# Python, What is wrong in the following code? range(20,-1,0) return's an error

Tags: python

```
for i in range(20,-1,0):
    print(i)
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    for i in range(20,-1,0):
ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero
```

Comment: what you are trying to do ?

Comment: It told you the error: `range() arg 3 must not be zero`

Comment: You're specifying a step of `0`, which is impossible. How can we get from `20` to `-1` counting by `0`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the error from the traceback.

Comment: flip the third and second arguments: list(range(20,0,-1))

Answer (score 7):

`range` takes three arguments, start, stop, and step.

```
range(20,-1,0):
```

says to go from `20` to `-1` in steps of size `0`.

That doesn't make sense, and so python threw an error.

Answer (score 3):

In for loop:

```
range(20,-1,0)
#            ^^ can't be zero , Obviously Jump can't be zero
```

To iterate in reverse order, you need to pass  third argument is negative (read comments):

```
>>> range(20,-1, -1)  # 
[20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> range(20,-1, -2)
[20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

To iterate in normal order you need to pass +ve number:

```
>>> range(0, 20, 1) # == range(0, 20) == range(20)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> range(0, 20, 2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Read Python doc:

> #### [range(stop)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)
>
> ```
>    range(start, stop[, step])
> ```
>
> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is
>   most often used in for loops. The arguments must be plain integers. If
>   the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument
>   is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain
>   integers `[start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]`. If step is
>   positive, the last element is the largest `start + i * step` less than
>   stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest `start + i
>   * step` greater than stop. **`step` must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised)**.

Hence you are getting `ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero` exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
>>> range(20,-1,-1)
[20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

The third element is the step, which couldn't be zero, and if you are going backward should be negative number other wise positive number. Call `help(range):`

> ```
> range(...)
> range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers
> ```
>
> Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
>   `range(i, j)` returns `[i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1];` start (!) defaults to `0`.
>   When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement). For
>   example, `range(4)` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.  The end point is omitted!
>   These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.